# is there a way to ensure electron-vite/rollup uses absolute references to compiled assets?

Tags: reactjs, electron, vite, rollupjs, electron-react

## Details

I am writing an electron-vite application, that uses react-router-dom for it's routing. I deploy the "renderer" folder to vercel, along with a vercel.json at root.

Now the app works fine when i navigate starting from the root domain but once i copy the url (e.g. https://example.com/app/transfers/id) to another tab, it just displays a blank, screen.

Investigating the console, i can see it fails to get the bundled js file generated by rollup.

[image]

Then when I check out the "sources" tab, I can see this is because it tries to access the assets
folder using a relative paths :
[image]

I know this is the issue because, when i enable Local overrides in developer tools, and manually remove the "." in front of the paths, everything works fine.

[image]

and this makes sense because we should be looking for the generated bundles at: `https://example.com/assets/bundle.js`
and not:
`https://example.com/app/transfers/id/assets/bundle.js`

I understand this could easily be fixed by switching to HashRouter instead of Browser Router, infact  i have code that switches, between the HashRouter and BrowserRouter, based on whether you're in the browser on running the electron app.

But I would love to avoid using HashRouter in the browser if possible.

## What I have tried:

I know of the vite base path config option. setting that to `/` still yields no good results (bundled html remains the same, no matter what i pass to `base`):

[image]

So is there some other way to solve this or a way to make sure the bundles are always looked up at their absolute paths?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use `HashRouter`. Anyway, you can try to see if the [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) property of `BrowserRouter` solves your problem.

Comment: Hey thanks @Arkellys, so to quote the react-router-dom page on `HashRouter`:  `We strongly recommend you do not use HashRouter unless you absolutely have to.` . My other reasons are purely aesthetic reasons. would love to avoid having urls like `https://example.com/#/app/transfers/id`, when i don't need to

Comment: I believe Electron is part of the "absolutely have to". I've read some people said `MemoryRouter` works too.

Comment: Yes, of course, in the question, i actually mentioned that. i use browserrouter in the browser and HashRouter in electron. i was able to solve this issue by simply placing: `<base href="/" />` in my head tag in the html file. interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to simply be to place a `base` tag in my html `head` tag, like so:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Electron</title>
  <base href="/" />
</head>
```

according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base):

> The  HTML element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs in a document. There can be only one  element in a document.
>
> A document's used base URL can be accessed by scripts with Node.baseURI. If the document has no  elements, then baseURI defaults to location.href.

An perfect solution for this case since the issue was with vite/rollup generating relative URL's for my generated JS and css bundles.

Cheers.